# my local host in visual studio is going to a directory instead of the site now

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013, resx

I am not able to get the site working anymore. I don't know what happened but everytime I go to the site it starts giving me a file directory instead. How can I fix this?

[image of what im getting when I build the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdS2n.png)

Comment: hmmm I have experience with apache and php and that happens when apache can't find the php interpreter, I don't know if this is applicable here :(

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your IIS version, these solutions should work:

1) Open web.config on your MVC root project (not on the Views directory) and check this element to be exist:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

2) Make sure your directory browsing for localhost server application pool set to "Disable" (IIS Manager - Features View - Directory Browsing - Disable, by default this property is Disable). See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx for more details. Click "Test Settings" to verify virtual directory & path settings.

3) Check default route on your MVC project, then on publish mode set the project as IIS application. Make sure your site's default route has proper declaration.

4) For 64-bit host only (Win 7/Windows Server 2008 and above): Install 32-bit version of `aspnet_regiis` if your MVC application built on 32-bit platform. The 32-bit project should run on 32-bit environment without problems, some 32-bit app running directly on 64-bit machine using 32-bit registers may cause several oddities and compatibility issues.

The issue can narrowed if you tell what IIS version installed on your machine (specifically includes 32-bit/64-bit platform) and MVC version to build your project.